# Group by ID and Order by date

Tags: date, cakephp, group-by

```
$lastComments = $this->Comment->find('all', array('fields' => array('Comment.news_id', 'Comment.date', 'Comment.content'),
                'group' => array('Comment.news_id, Comment.date'),    
                'order' => array('Comment.date DESC'))
        );
```

The idea is to get **latest comment** from unique topics (1 comment - 1 topic).

This code doesn't handle unique ID's (unique topics), how Can I fix that?

Distinct doesn't work.

```
$lastComments = $this->Comment->find('all', array('fields' => array('Comment.news_id', 'Comment.date', 'Comment.content'),
                'group' => array('Comment.news_id'),    
                'order' => array('Comment.date DESC'))
        );
```

This code will return unique topics but order by date doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be help you a bit...Just try this

```
$this->Post->find('all',array( 'order' => array('id DESC') )  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Comment->find('first', array('order'=>array('Comment.id DESC')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned DISTINCT didn't work.  Did you have trouble using the DISTINCT syntax in CakePHP, or did using DISTINCT correctly not yield the correct results?  I'd try:

```
$lastComments = $this->Comment->find('all', array('fields' => 
                                                    array('DISTINCT Comment.news_id', 'Comment.date', 'Comment.content'),
                                                 'order' => array('Comment.date DESC'))
    );
```

Comment: I tried that before I posted :/

Any other ideas?

Thanks for the reply.
Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

If it can help, I had the same problem without cakephp, the solution was to use a **max(date)**

Prehaps something like that in cakephp :

```
$lastComments = $this->Comment->find('all', 
array('fields' => array('Comment.news_id', 
                        'Comment.date', 
                        'Comment.content'),
                'group' => array('Comment.news_id'),    
                'order' => array('max(Comment.date) DESC'))
        );
```