# Cakephp 1.3 - Ordering a group of results

Tags: sql, cakephp, model

I have the following model:

```
$values = $this->PtlUserdata->find('all', array(

    'fields' => array(

        'PtlUserdata.field', 
        'PtlUserdata.value',
        'PtlUserdata.timestamp'

     ), 

     'conditions' => array(

         'PtlUserdata.user_id' => $user->get('id'),

     ),

     'order' => array('PtlUserdata.timestamp' => 'DESC'),
     'group' => array('PtlUserdata.field')

));
```

I'm trying to order the results by timestamp and then group the results by field, so I can get the most recent record with that field name.

Does anybody know how to do this is cakephp?

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Comment: That looks fine to me - what's not happening that you are expecting to happen?

Comment: Hi, whats currently happening is the results are not being ordered by the timestamp before they're added to the group. I want only the most recent results in the group.

Comment: Basically, I want to do the following in a cakephp model: SELECT t1.* FROM ptl_userdata t1 WHERE t1.user_id = 2885 AND t1.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.timestamp) FROM ptl_userdata t2 WHERE t2.user_id = 2885 AND t2.field = t1.field)
   GROUP BY t1.field

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior for the database. You will have to come up with some sort of workaround to do it.

An idea: [CakePHP: Group by ID and Order by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858408/cakephp-group-by-id-and-order-by-date)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
$values = $this->PtlUserdata->find('all', array(

'fields' => array(

    'PtlUserdata.field', 
    'PtlUserdata.value',
    'max(PtlUserdata.timestamp)'

 ), 

 'conditions' => array(

     'PtlUserdata.user_id' => $user->get('id'),
     'PtlUserdata.timestamp' => 'max(PtlUserdata.timestamp)',
 ),

 'group' => array(
      'PtlUserdata.field',
      'PtlUserdata.timestamp'
      )

));
```

I haven't had the chance to test this but you definitely need to be grouping by `PtlUserdata.timestamp`.