# cakephp order by ID

Tags: cakephp

I have a small CakePHP app in which I retrieve some client information in a table. In the main table where all my clients show up I would like to sort them by ID (highest ID on top)

My current code is as follows:

```
    <?php foreach($clients as $client) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $client['Client']['id']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($client['Client']['client_name'], array('action' => 'view', $client['Client']['id']), array('class' => 'view')); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $client['Client']['client_contact']?></td>
        <td><a href="tel:<?php echo $client['Client']['client_phone']?>"><?php echo $client['Client']['client_phone']?></a></td>
        <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $client['Client']['client_email']?>"><?php echo $client['Client']['client_email']?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I implement the related sort-order here? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: what is your current output got after tries

Comment: In the current output there seems to be no apparent order, ids come out as : 19, 20, 25, 22, 24, 26, 34, 27....

Comment: take it for reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858408/cakephp-group-by-id-and-order-by-date

Comment: You should be sorting your data when you query the database rather than sorting an array in your View. You need to show your code used for retrieving `$clients` and mention what version of CakePHP you are using as this is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `order` in your find function.Like below code

```
$this->Client->find('all', array(
    'order' => array('Client.id' => 'desc')
));
```

Comment: Thank you Karan, but how do I implement this in my table's foreach?

Comment: you don't need to implement it on foreach. Returned array will have top ids first.

Comment: Perfect, I got it working now - thank you very much Karan